# Error with if statement and multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm having a problem with if statement that's checking if input is correct.
It when I input M or F it prints out "Wrong input" and I don't understand it very clearly.

```
def check(aw,iw):
    if abs(aw-iw)<5 :
        print "Your weight is normal."
    elif abs(aw-iw)>5 and abs(aw-iw)<15 :
        print "Your weight is about normal."
    else:
        print "Your weight is not normal."
    return

print "Enter your gender (M/F)"
gender=raw_input()
if gender!='M' or gender!='F':
    print "Wrong input."
else:
    if gender=='M':
        w=raw_input("Enter your weight (kg) :")
        h=raw_input("Enter your height (cm) :")
        idw=110-h
        check(w,idw)
    else:
        w = raw_input("Enter your weight (kg) :")
        h = raw_input("Enter your height (cm) :")
        idw = 110 - h
        check(w, idw)
```

Comment: could you fix your indentation

Comment: Get rid of the outer if-block and do `if gender == "M": ... elif gender == "F": ... else: print "Wrong input."`.

Answer (score 1):

Every input is either not equal to `M` or not equal to `F` (e.g., `M` is not equal to `F`). Instead you need to check if your input is not equal to `M` **and** not equal to `F`:

```
if gender != 'M' and gender != 'F':
    # Here ------^
    print "Wrong input."
```

Or, more elegantly, use the `not in` operator:

```
if gender not in ('M', 'F'):
    print "Wrong input."
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
if gender!='M' or gender!='F':
```

It will always resolve to `False` since `gender` can never be both `M` and `F`.

You can use `in` instead:

```
if gender in ('M', 'F'):
```

Alternatively:

```
if (gender != 'M') and (gender != 'F'):
```

Also, remove the line `gender=int(gender)`: it should always fail.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice,I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already got your answer in the previous answers to your question. i would just like to add the fact you appreciate some visualizations to the simple problem that you have faced but very delicate one for every beginner.

You have **or** doing this-
when you write

> M

python checks if

> M is **!=**(not equal to) M

but M is equal to M. so it results in false and then checks if

> M != F

and sees its true. The **or** operation thus does the following-

- true + true = true
- true + false= true
- false + true = true ....... this one
- false + false = false

As your one resembles the 3rd one it returns true and python says "wrong input".

if you write **and** then it goes something like-
is

> M!=M

returns false, **and**

> M!=F

returns true.

In **and** its like-

- true + true= true
- true + false= false
- false + true= false
- false + false= false

So python returns false for the if statement and follows what you want it to do in the next lines of code. I hope it makes it very clear.

And remove gender=int(gender) its not necessary because python can recognize M and F as char and you need not turn it into integer value or ascii here.

Comment: Thanks,stupid mistake i guess...Wasn't paying enough attention,sorri for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
gender=int(gender)
```

and make changes to

```
 if gender!='M' or gender!='F':
```

as

```
if gender!='M' and gender!='F':
```

Comment: Stupid mistake,just wasn't paying enough attention,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should use `<=` to include limits in your evaluation.

```
def check(aw,iw):
    if abs(aw-iw)<=5 :
        print "Your weight is normal."
```

You can shorten `elif abs(aw-iw)>5 and abs(aw-iw)<15:`, since `if abs(aw-iw)<5` is not true, then it will always be higher than 5.

```
    #Instead of elif abs(aw-iw)>5 and abs(aw-iw)<15:
    elif abs(aw-iw)<=15:
        print "Your weight is about normal."
    else:
        print "Your weight is not normal."
    return
```

Instead of:

```
print "Enter your gender (M/F)"
gender=raw_input()
gender=int(gender)
```

You should use:

```
gender = raw_input('Enter yor gender (M/F)')
```

Where `int(gender)` would cause an error, since the input you want from `gender=raw_input()` gives a string in letters.

You should change that `or` for an `and`, since if using `or`, if your input is `'M'`, then `gender != 'F'` will give `True` and it will run the `if` condition.

```
#Instead of if gender!='M' or gender!='F':
if gender!='M' and gender!='F':
    print "Wrong input."
```

Here you should use `int(raw_input())` for your variables to be evaluated as integers and be able to add or subtract them. And since you are doing the same code wether it's `M` or `F`, there is no need to write another `if:` `else:` condition.

```
else:
    w = int(raw_input("Enter your weight (kg) :"))
    h = int(raw_input("Enter your height (cm) :"))
    idw = 110 - h
    check(w, idw)
```